# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returning null

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I want to manually bypass the user from spring Security using the following code:

```
User localeUser = new User();
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(localeUser ,null, localeUser .getAuthorities());
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);
        // Create a new session and add the security context.
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
return "dummyLogin";
```

The dummy login page(handled by tiles)internally calls a different Request Mapping in the same controller where i am trying to get the Authentication something like this.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Where i am getting null?

Comment: You are passing an empty User object to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken constructor. May be that is the reason you are getting null.

Comment: Also a null password (I think that's also illegal). Maybe if you show the stack trace?

Comment: password can be null, I would rather check if session is the same after you create it and in code which run getAuthentication. Log your session.getId() to check it.

Comment: Do you want to bypass the security only for some particular pages or particular user or for all ?

Comment: I want to bypass for all the pages for that particular session Id(User)

Comment: Also i checked the session ID in both the requests !its the same.Cant get the problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, I found the actual problem!
The issue was that I had marked the whole controller with security="none" in the security-context.xml.
So, when it was bounced from the first link to the 2nd, it didn't pass any security context with it!!
Sorry for the trouble, guys.

Comment: helped me to solve my issue , i put certain url pattern in ignore configuration , and result is null security context in those controller , removing from ignore configuration makes this controller as secure , eventually get the security context as desired

Answer (score 2):

Your localUser is null.So the auth become null.So no authentication object has been added to the security context.

Please have look at the doc

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html

It is better to have a customUserDetailsService

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService 

//implement the method which return a UserDetails Object
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
```

then you can use

```
    UserDetails userDetails= customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("name"); 
Authentication authentication= new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()) ; 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: localUser is not null!.its a custom user object of the application which on initialization self created the Ids and Details in it.

Comment: The first sentence is so right on point in my case. It should be highlighted

Answer (score 2):

**Additional Answer:** If you want to get logged-in user details for a non-secured url then you can add them to secured urls and assign as "permitAll" like this:

```
<http>
    //...

    <intercept-url pattern="/your/url/**" access="permitAll"/>

    //...
</http>
```

Then, you will be able to check the logged-in user if logged-in or get the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I was also a facing a similar issue. What the problem in my piece of code was that the Request Mapping prefix of my controller was ignored in my Security Token Config file, which was causing SecurityContextHolder to be null.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
Authentication authentication=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
localeUser .setUserNm(authentication.getName());
```

Comment: You don't have to comment it. Instead could you add your commnet to answer