# How to get current user inside Callable in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, callable

I need to get the current user inside function executed by a Callable. 
The methode used to execute my callables:

```
public static boolean run(List<Callable<Integer>> callables) {
    try {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor.invokeAll(callables);
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        return true;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Inside the callable I call a function that need to get the current user, I try to use SecurityContextHolder:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
System.out.println("auth" + auth);
```

But this show me null.

Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191386/securitycontextholder-getcontext-getauthentication-returning-null This might help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i try to use session but the same probleme

Answer (score 2):

The SecurityContextHolder (by default) stores the SecurityContext via a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). It is only available in the thread that processes the request.

You have to get the SecurityContext (on the request thread) and pass it to each Callable before you execute them.

Answer (score 1):

Matt is correct RE: Spring storing the authentication inside of a thread local variable. You might be able to configure Spring Security to pass the security context from the parent thread to the one that is spawned by calling:

`SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);`

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html